# Android HttpsUrlConnection with POST data not work on Gingerbread

Tags: java, android, https, httpsurlconnection

I've written code to download some data from external server. The server is using self-signed certificate, need to have session cookie set and some POST data. Currently I have the following code:

```
private byte[] getResponse(URL url, String postData) 
    throws IOException, KeyManagementException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, 
    NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSocketFactory());

    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(postData);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    try {
        urlConnection.connect();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
        {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

On Ice Cream Sandwich and higher (API >= 14) everything works fine. The problem started when I tried to make the app work on API >= 8. It is now properly sending the request with GET and no params (CAPTCHA) but when it comes to getting the actual data urlConnection's connect method fails with no exception. The code for getSocketFactory() is:

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() 
    throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    KeyManagementException
{
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.historiapojazdu);
    Certificate ca;
    try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    } finally {
    caInput.close();
    }
    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

EDIT: I've just realized that connect method apparently worked but it didn't follow redirect on the response so input stream was always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it myself. It looks like HttpsUrlConnection simply does not follow redirects on API 10 and lower for some reason even despite implicitly calling setInstanceFollowRedirects(true). It is just ignoring that setting. I've worked that around with this code just after calling urlConnection.connect():

```
String redirect = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
        if(redirect != null)    //truth before ICS
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();

            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(redirect)).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSocketFactory());

            OutputStream os2 = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os2, "UTF-8"));
            writer2.write(postData);
            writer2.flush();
            writer2.close();
            os2.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
        }
```